# 'Break' a table, 4 columns, two for each object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm showing in a table some attributes(just two) from records from my database.

It's works, but now I want to 'break' my table in 4 columns.

Example:

Before

**maker**  --------   **model**

apple     ---------    iphone

samsung   ----    s3

motorola   ----   razr i

After:
**maker**  --------   **model**   ----  **maker**  --------   **model**

apple     ---------    iphone ------------ samsung   ------    s3

motorola   ----   razr i

So, instead one object, I want get two.

But, I don't find how can I do this. Any suggestion please?

For now, my table is that:

```
<l><b><%= t("reports.graphs.mobiles") %></b></l>
<table class="zebra-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th><%= t('labels.maker')%> / <%= t('labels.model')%></th>
  <th><%= t('labels.distribution')%></th>
  <th><%= t('labels.maker')%> / <%= t('labels.model')%></th>
  <th><%= t('labels.distribution')%></th>
</tr>
<% makers_model.each do |maker_model| %>
<tr>
  <td width="50%" ><%= maker_model[0] %></td>
  <td><%= ((maker_model[1].to_f)/(makers_model.inject(0) { |sum, tuple| sum += tuple[1] }) * 100).round(2).to_s + "%" %></td>
  <td width="50%" ><%= maker_model[0] %></td>
  <td><%= ((maker_model[1].to_f)/(makers_model.inject(0) { |sum, tuple| sum += tuple[1] }) * 100).round(2).to_s + "%" %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Thanks and please, sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% makers_model.each_slice(2) do |slice| %>
<tr>
  <% slice.each do |maker_model| %>
    <td width="50%" ><%= maker_model[0] %></td>
    <td><%= ((maker_model[1].to_f)/(makers_model.inject(0) { |sum, tuple| sum += tuple[1] }) *   100).round(2).to_s + "%" %></td>
  <% end %>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Each slice will split them into sections of whatever number you specify.  So if I understand what you want you want them split into groups of 2 then iterating over that group for each row in your table